# Javascript: How to conditionally extend selection by one character

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I'm an objective C programmer who has needed to quickly learn about Javascript over the last two weeks for a new app I am making. There are a few things I haven't been able to figure out, so I have decided to ask about them here.

This time, this is my question:

If I have a selection that is a single word, how do I check to see if the character before the word is a double quote (quotation marks), and if it is, extend the selection to include them?

other relevant points (due to the rest of the program):

- this only needs to happen if the focusNode is the same as the anchorNode
- the selection could have been made forwards or backwards
- I don't want the selection changing unless there is a double quote
- It really only needs to check for double quotes before the selection, but perhaps I could extend it also behave the same way for double quotes after the selection
- do NOT ignore white spaces
- javascript not jquery

here is what I have tried, that seems to be the kind of thing I should do, but due to my lack of experience in Javascript it doesn't work (And I apologise for stupid mistakes, and ignorant uses of the wrong things):

```
    var selection       = window.getSelection();
    var focusNode       = selection.focusNode;
    var focusOffset     = selection.focusOffset;
    var anchorNode      = selection.anchorNode;
    var anchorOffset    = selection.anchorOffset;

    if (anchorNode === focusNode ) {
    var quoteRange = document.createRange();
    var quoteString = "";

    if ((focusOffset > anchorOffset) && anchorOffset > 0){ //selection is forwards
       quoteRange.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset);
        quoteRange.setEnd(anchorNode, anchorOffset - 1);
        quoteString = quoteRange.toString();
    } else if ((focusOffset < anchorOffset) && focusOffset > 0){ //selection is backwards
       quoteRange.setStart(focusNode, focusOffset);
        quoteRange.setEnd(focusNode, focusOffset - 1);
        quoteString = quoteRange.toString();
     }

    console.log(quoteString);

    if (quoteString ===  "\"") {
       selection.modify("extend", "backward", "character");
    }

}
```

I get the feeling there is something that should be obvious to people more experienced than me, that I am doing wrong.

In my version, "quoteString" always ends up empty when (as far as I can tell)it shouldn't be.

Comment: I've had some experience with this and used a javascript library called rangy. Maybe it can help you as well.
https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Comment: yes, I've seen rangy mentioned quite a lot. The author of it seems to promote it here a lot. I'm hoping to do it without a library though, as that seems to be overkill for what seems like it should be a simple problem. Basically all I need to get is the text that is in a range. (assuming I am getting the ranges correctly). Thanks anyway.

Comment: In what way does it not work? The code looks sensible. Also, in general `anchorNode` and `focusNode` are not guaranteed to be text nodes, although you may know that and not need to handle cases where they're not.

Comment: Regarding Rangy, these days I try not to promote it if there's a simple solution without it, but I admit I probably did promote it a little too enthusiastically on here in the early days.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am calling this after a user long presses on a UIWebView in my iOS app. A long press automatically (in most cases) selects a single word. So in this case it should always be a text node? (I honestly am not sure, as I know little about Javascript/html). I do have another issue in cases when this doesn't apply (really short nodes, there it seems to select the tags too), but I figure I'll get to that separately. - So, you are saying that this should work? The console.log is always empty/blank, but if I check if (quoteString === ""), that evaluates as false too. I'm perplexed.

Comment: With my testing I have also noticed a strange behaviour that seems to be occurring: When you select a word with a long tap in iOS, it selects it as if it was a forward swipe. But for some reason when the word is immediately following a double quote, it seems to select it as if it were a backwards swipe. In reality it is not a swipe in either case, it is just a long tap. Perhaps I should look into this apparent behaviour more, it might give me a clue as to why this is not working, and if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @TimDown thanks Tim, since you confirmed that the code I posted looked sensible, you inspired me to look within it to figure out what the problem could be, and I found the answer. See the answer I posted. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woohoo! I got it to work. It seems that the problem was that the range I was creating was in a negative direction. When I swapped the setEnd and the setStart around, everything worked as expected.  :)

```
if (anchorNode === focusNode ) {
    var quoteRange = document.createRange();
    var quoteString = "";
    if ((focusOffset > anchorOffset) && anchorOffset > 0){ //selection is forwards
       quoteRange.setEnd(anchorNode, anchorOffset);
        quoteRange.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset - 1);
        quoteString = quoteRange.toString();
            } else if ((focusOffset < anchorOffset) && focusOffset > 0){ //selection is backwards
       quoteRange.setEnd(focusNode, focusOffset);
        quoteRange.setStart(focusNode, focusOffset - 1);
        quoteString = quoteRange.toString();
                }
    console.log(quoteString);

   if (quoteString ===  "\"") {
       selection.modify("extend", "backward", "character");
```